# How to automatically convert timezone while loading into MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv, datetime

I am trying to load a table which has DATETIME datatype in MySQL. The source is a csv file which has values in UTC. Is there a way where i can mention to automatically convert them to EST while loading data.

I am using "LOAD DATA from S3" in AWS to load data into Aurora Mysql.

Below is a sample for one column.

````
 birth_dt in UTC     =+ birth_dt in table as EST
 =+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+  =+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+
1990-09-20 23:00:00  =+   1990-09-20 19:00:00
 =+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+  =+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+ ```
````

Comment: Share some sample data and expected result in a tabular format.

Comment: updated the question with sample and expected data. Sorry for the editing as i am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Could you share the `load data local infile...` query here which you used to upload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before inserting directly into the column store in a temporary variable then convert into 'EST' and insert.

Here is the sample load file use the `set` line and change as per your table and column name.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path of csv' INTO TABLE table_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(col1,col2,....,@utc)
SET date_column = CONVERT_TZ(@utc,'+0:00','-5:00');
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this out. But,i was looking more of an option in create table statement where it automatically converts.

Comment: You said the import will be from csv right? so what happens if you directly add a insert or other methods?

Comment: Yes. i am importing from csv. This is an existing code where we have almost 50 datetime column in 7 tables. So, instead of going and editing all the codes, thought of just altering the DDL.

Comment: Are you going to change the datetime inside the tables(existing) or you need to change while importing(New)? Make it clear

Comment: i am trying to change while importing new data into the table. But not through changing the existing code. Is there a way i can mention in the DDL of the table ?

Comment: Then you need to use a trigger while insert since you said around 50 columns it's better if you handle while importing. Or once inserted you need to update the table using the `convert_tz`

Comment: If it is not clear enough then please edit your question and elaborate in detail by giving us more info.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will try changing the code itself. Creating a trigger for 50 columns will impact the performance.

Comment: yes. If you are doing by load file then my answer will be best.